# Python Inverse Kinematics package

Tags: python, robotics, inverse-kinematics

I am building a robotic arm with 6 DOF using arduino and 6 servo motors.

I made myself a Python interface using serial communication so that I can write: `move_motor(angle1=45, angle2=37)` and the servo motors will move accordingly.

Now i am getting to the IK part, and I'm looking for a good package where you set the arm lengths, and then you can give it `(x,y,z,theta)` and it will return you the angle for each motor.

Is there a good package available? Or at least something that i can play with for my needs?

Comment: Have you looked at https://code.google.com/p/robotics-toolbox-python/ ?

Comment: I have, and there are some compatibility issues with the matplotlib package (with importing matplotlib.Axes3D). Since i saw the last edit was from 2008 i figured there might be something newer... 

I also found no examples of people actually using it. Is it worth the while of making it compatible? 

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

As your problem is quite simple, I think the best for you is to solve the inverse kinematics (IK) problem by quadratic programming (QP). In Python, you can solve QPs in a few lines of code using e.g. the CVXOPT library (I published [a tutorial with some code here](https://scaron.info/blog/linear-programming-in-python-with-cvxopt.html)). Also, I wrote is [an example of IK solver in Python](https://github.com/Tastalian/pymanoid/blob/master/pymanoid/inverse_kinematics.py) that uses CVXOPT as QP solver. It is more complex than the problem at hand, but you can take a look at it for inspiration.

The useful part is this function:

```
def compute_velocity(self, q, qd):
    P = zeros(self.I.shape)
    r = zeros(self.q_max.shape)
    for obj in self.objectives:
        J = obj.jacobian(q)
        P += obj.weight * dot(J.T, J)
        r += obj.weight * dot(-obj.velocity(q, qd).T, J)
    if self.K_doflim is not None:
        qd_max = minimum(self.qd_max, self.K_doflim * (self.q_max - q))
        qd_min = maximum(self.qd_min, self.K_doflim * (self.q_min - q))
    else:
        qd_max = self.qd_max
        qd_min = self.qd_min
    G = vstack([+self.I, -self.I])
    h = hstack([qd_max, -qd_min])
    if self.constraints:
        A = vstack([c.jacobian() for c in self.constraints])
        b = hstack([c.velocity() for c in self.constraints])
        return cvxopt_solve_qp(P, r, G, h, A, b)
    return cvxopt_solve_qp(P, r, G, h)
```

It basically solves the global IK problem (finding a joint-angle vector 'q') by *differential IK*, that is to say, by computing a velocity 'qd' that drives the system toward the solution. It is essentially the idea behind the [Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm).

Comment: Gotcha. I updated the answer, it is now more self-contained, while still pointing out to external links for further reference.